# Android: Subir imagenes al servidor de manera asincrona

Tags: android

Estoy enviando un JSON de imagenes con unos datos, mi duda es como le tengo que hacer para enviar las imagenes de manera asincron, osea que no tenga que esperar a que cargen todas las imagenes para que se puedan enviar sino como van terminado de cargar que se vayan enviando.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {//ejecuta nuestras tareas principales
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();//hago una instancia de checkin
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();//creo un JSONObject

        ArrayList<Bitmap> listOfBitmaps = (ArrayList<Bitmap>) params[0];//Obtengo mi Arreglo de objetos para despues pasarlos a un array lis de Bitmap
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();//permitira la salida de los bytes

        ArrayList<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();//creo un arrayLIsto de String

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfBitmaps.size(); i++){//itero el arreglo
            listOfBitmaps.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);//se comprime la imagen
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();//codifica el path a un arreglo de byte
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);//codifico ese byteArray a base64 y despues a scrintg

            listOfStrings.add(encoded);//agrego al arreglo de strings
        }
        jsonObject.put("folio", checkIn.getFolio());//paso el folio al JSONObject
        jsonObject.put("images", listOfStrings);//le paso al JSONObject los codigos de las iameges
        StringEntityHC4 entityHC4 = new StringEntityHC4(jsonObject.toString(), ContentType.create("json/application", "UTF-8"));//la direccion del servidor a la que va a apuntar
        HttpPutHC4 httpPutHC4 = new HttpPutHC4(DynamicUrl.BASE_URL+DynamicUrl.SERVER_HOST+":"+DynamicUrl.SERVER_PORT+"/api/checkkin");//la direccion del dervidor al que va a apuntar
        httpPutHC4.setEntity(entityHC4);//seteo los datos que tengo en el JSONObject
        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();//La configuracion del servidor va a ser default
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPutHC4);//Obtengo la respuesta del servidor

        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {//si el estatus de la respuesta es igual a 200
            JSONObject jsonRosponse = new JSONObject(EntityUtilsHC4.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));//creo un JSONObject y le paso el JSON que recibio de la sespuesta del servidor

            if (jsonRosponse.getString("code").equals("OK")) {//checo que el JSON tenga la clave OK
                System.out.println("Las imagenes se guardaron correctamente");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error al subir las imagenes");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: si te entiendo bien, quieres que se envie asincrona 1 por 1 las imagenes?

Comment: Hola sioesi, asi es quiero que se vaya enviando de una por una porque habarcan demasiadas hojas si envio todas las imagenes ya que estan en Base 64

Comment: ¿Las peticiones las quieres realizar de forma secuencial o todas al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Todas al mismo tiempo y de ahi como vayan terminando se van enviando pero de una por una

Answer (score 3):

Solo debes cambiar todo su tratamiento de arreglo de imagenes al for y enviar 1 por 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfBitmaps.size(); i++) { //itero el arreglo
        listOfBitmaps.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream); //se comprime la imagen
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(); //codifica el path a un arreglo de byte
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT); //codifico ese byteArray a base64 y despues a scrintg
        jsonObject.put("folio", checkIn.getFolio()); //paso el folio al JSONObject
        jsonObject.put("imagen", encoded); //le paso al JSONObject los codigos de las iameges
        StringEntityHC4 entityHC4 = new StringEntityHC4(jsonObject.toString(), ContentType.create("json/application", "UTF-8")); //la direccion del servidor a la que va a apuntar
        HttpPutHC4 httpPutHC4 = new HttpPutHC4(DynamicUrl.BASE_URL + DynamicUrl.SERVER_HOST + ":" + DynamicUrl.SERVER_PORT + "/api/checkkin"); //la direccion del dervidor al que va a apuntar
        httpPutHC4.setEntity(entityHC4); //seteo los datos que tengo en el JSONObject
        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(); //La configuracion del servidor va a ser default
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPutHC4); //Obtengo la respuesta del servidor

        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) { //si el estatus de la respuesta es igual a 200
            JSONObject jsonRosponse = new JSONObject(EntityUtilsHC4.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())); //creo un JSONObject y le paso el JSON que recibio de la sespuesta del servidor

            if (jsonRosponse.getString("code").equals("OK")) { //checo que el JSON tenga la clave OK
                System.out.println("La imagen se guardo correctamente");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error al subir la imagen");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error");
        }
    }
```

Ya no envias un arreglo en `jsonObject.put("images", listOfStrings);` si no que envias `jsonObject.put("imagen", encoded);` y cada iteración del for es una subida al servidor.

**EDICION**

Respecto a tu pregunta ***¿Como a un ImageView le entrego la URL de una imagen?***

```
public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Bitmap > {

    private String url;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ImageLoadTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        this.url = url;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...params) {
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Lo puedes llamar `new ImageLoadTask(url, imageView).execute();`

Te recomiendo que lo hagas tambien en una tarea asincrona, ya que como estas simulando carga de imagenes y son de internet, puede que alguna falle, si falla esto no afectara a tu aplicación, pero de todas formas este codigo seria sencillo sin una tarea asincrona.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url_image) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_image);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Esto es una referencia de la [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953632/how-to-set-image-from-url-for-imageview) en StackOverFlow Ingles

Comment: Hola sioesi ya habia pensado en tu respuesta y funciona, muchas gracias. Agradesco tu ayuda.

Comment: de nada @Javierfr de todas formas!, te aconsejo que si tienes tiempo, averigues como subir las imagenes como archivos y no en codigo base64, ya que como tu experimentaste, es muy engorroso el tema de tantos caracteres.

Comment: sip. Gracias :D

Comment: UNA PREGUNTA MAS

Comment: dime @Javierfr cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: estoy simulando que traigo unas imagenes entonces en SOUAPUI pongo la ruta de unas imagenes de internet en mi JSON de SOUAPUI, pero como paso esa ruta de la imagen a BItmap o como le hago para que se muestre en mi IMAGEVIEW

Comment: te deje una clase asincrona que obtiene un bitmap de una URL de imagen @Javierfr